# Programmatically change the program icon

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, icons

I'm developing on VS 2010/ C#.

Does any one know how to change the software icon programmatically?

I actually want my software to have one icon under Windows 7 and another for Windows XP in the same software installation.

Comment: If you are talking about the launcher icon, then your installer is what adds that.  So, you need to change your installer, in order to advise further I would need to know what installer you are using.

Comment: not regurd to the installation process.. I want that after the installation process I'll get under Windows7 c:\program Files\mysoftware.exe(with Icon1) and under windows XP c:\program Files\mysoftware.exe(with Icon2)... the software do the same action in both OS but I need them to be diffrent Icons...

Comment: This is pretty hard to do, the icon is embedded as an *unmanaged* resource in the EXE.  Best approach is to have your installer create a .lnk file with a custom build action.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a winform app, you can write below code in the formload event of the main form.

Use this link to find operating system : 
http://andrewensley.com/2009/06/c-detect-windows-os-part-1/

and then write below code to set icon.

```
private void InvestorReportingFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Icon = Properties.Resources.coins;            
        }
```

Comment: I don' t think this is the answer because it just changes the form's icon. He asks to change the program icon, or application.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"Stringpath");
```