# C# WPF change the program icon

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF program with C#. I want the user to be able to change it's icon for what ever he wants (titlebar, taskbar and thumbnails).
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12059641/4416750) might fix it for you. Assign the user-selected image to the `Icon` property of the form.

Comment: If you think the question can be answered by another question here on Stack Overflow please flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting links.

Comment: @ChrisF The question isn't a duplicate though. The answer was applicable to this question, but the linked question had other conditions this question doesn't (the linked question asked about differentiating between two different operating systems). Would this still be a case to flag as a duplicate? Thanks.